Is a name of person in an blog interview personal identifiable information that requires author disclosure in privacy policy?
Lets say one has a blog and makes an in person interview with someone.
The blog mentions this person name.
The interview then is posted to the blog.
Except for that,blog doesn't collect anything from visitors- no cookies, no ads, no IP addresses nor even visit timestamps.
So the question is, in such scenario, would author of the blog need to disclose information about himself in privacy policy?

GDPR takes a lot of effort to read and to understand, just in case you don't know where it is, it's here: https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32016R0679

I agree with @metablaster, your question shows such a poor understanding of the GDPR that you are at a huge risk publishing a blog. You need to familiarise yourself with your obligations so you can actually ask the tight questions.

Unless there's some reason the subject thought this would be an anonymous interview (e.g. previous subjects' identities have been hidden), I don't see how they could expect privacy when agreeing to be interviewed for your blog.

An interviewee's name falls under right-of-publicity
If you have a right to publicity or not depends heavily on the jurisdiction. Typically, an Interview is covered by those rights, and not by gdpr.
site owners need an impressum anyway
An owner of a website needs to provide an impressum or contact address that suffices the requirements of the law where the content is hosted. What is required there depends on jurisdiction. Sometimes a PO box suffices, other times you need a physical address.

Different  thing then. Thanks for answer

The conclusion is that since interviewee name is PII and it would be stored,then one would have to disclose controller name to that person
(at least under GDPR).
One probably wouldn't have to have disclosure in privacy policy publicly accessible.
